# Including single-header-library in multiple files in C++

Tags: c++, svg, include

I'm writing app to convert `SVG` to custom structures for further use. For parsing SVG file to C++ structures I'm using `nanosvg` library, which is written in single header file (both declarations and implementation).

Implementation is enabled by `#define NANOSVG_IMPLEMENTATION` which enables reading implementations by compiler.

Problem is, I want to include this library in multiple files across project (in various structures like path, shape, etc.), so I've just `#include <nanosvg/nanosvg.h>`, but that makes it import only declaration. But defining `NANOSVG_IMPLEMENTATION` makes it declared across project, so now every `#include <nanosvg/nanosvg.h>` includes also bodies for functions, and that makes compiler throw lots of errors.

I want to keep classes apart, just for sake of easier further modification (looking for file name in project tree is way faster than `F12`-ing everything to the bottom, and wondering if that file contains that class for sure), so I didn't decided to mash everything into one file, yet.
Is there any way to restrict "area of effect" of #define, so every file would be loaded separately, or any way to load it one time "once for all"?

Answer (score 3):

C++ (like C) uses a model of separate compilation. Each Translation Unit is compiled independently, and then the results are linked together. Practically speaking, each .cpp file and all its headers form a Translation Unit.

Hence, you need one `#define NANOSVG_IMPLEMENTATION` in one .cpp file. It's as simple as that. That can be as simple as just

```
#define NANOSVG_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <nanosvg/nanosvg.h>
```

Nothing more.

Comment: Not true. Before linking first you will have to compile. If you are using any symbol from the header file in any .cpp file, you will have to include the header otherwise you will fail to compile only. SO this solution will not work

Comment: @Sisir: The question is where `#define NANOSVG_IMPLEMENTATION` goes (one .cpp file), not where `#include <nanosvg/nanosvg.h>` goes (before every use)

Comment: @MSalters It goes right before the #include directive in any one source file among all.

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni: How is that different from what I wrote?

Comment: I did so, I defined guard just once, in random file, and it was still causing problems.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a separate static or dynamic library C project that would consist of a single translation unit - that header file with `NANOSVG_IMPLEMENTATION` defined. And then link that library into your C++ project.

Note that attempt to built it as C++ code may not work or at least would cause massive amount of warnings.

Answer (score 0):

The owner's git repository does this without problem,
You should check and adapt your solution to that.
https://github.com/memononen/nanosvg/tree/master/example

If you have to redefine impl, you should use #undef macro,
But i guess you only have to expand Implementation Once, and include the source that contains definition wherever you want to use it